# Map Without Lift

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I want to show if $M$ is compact orientable surface of genus $2$, then there exists continuous map $f : M \rightarrow S^1$ with no lift to continuous map $\overline{f} : M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I just know that $M$ must be homeomorphic to torus of genus $2$ and if $\overline{f}$ exists we must have $f^{\star}(\pi_1(M))\subseteq p^{\star}(\pi_1(\mathbb{R}))$ where $p : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$ is covering map, but I have no idea how to construct such function.

Comment: Hint: What is the fundamental group of the real line? What would be its image under a homomorphism?

Comment: Do you know what $\pi_1(M)$ is? Can you find a non-trivial element represented by a loop that $M$ retracts onto?

Comment: @MoisheKohan it is $0$. How does that help me?

Comment: @ronno yes,  it is $\langle a,b,c,d|aba^{-1}b^{-1}cdc^{-1}d^{-1} \rangle$. For the second question I don't know the answer.

Comment: What are $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ on $M$?

Comment: Well, can you think of any map $M\to S^1$ which induces a nontrivial homomorphism of fundamental groups? What tools do you know that would allow you to construct a map $M\to S^1$ inducing a given homomorphism of fundamental groups?

Comment: @ronno ok I got it. Thanks

Comment: @MoisheKohan ok I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer follwoing hints from the comments. We can retract $M$ to $S^1$ by first retract $M$ to $S^1 \vee S^1$ by smashing it onto the plane, then  sending the first $S^1$ to the base point and map the second $S^1$ to $S^1$ by identity. Then if the meant map is denoted by $f : M\rightarrow S^1$, we have that $f^*(\pi_1(M))$ is not zero. If $f$ had a lift, by lifting criterion we have $f^{\star}(\pi_1(M))\subseteq p^{\star}(\pi_1(\mathbb{R}))=0$. So we get a contradiction and we get the map.